# AWS RDS MySQL some time get slow performance when update table1 set field='any word' where primarykey=1234

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, amazon-rds, aws

Normally when **update table1 set field='any word' where primarykey=1234** take 1sec. or less but sometimes random take much more time possible 500sec. or more.

I was set very well and never see high CPU, or IOPS

I use MySQL RDS 8.0.17 and workaround was down wait_time from 3600(default) to 200 to close sleep connections and then working better.

Comment: Looks like your "sleep connections" are not committing their transactions and thus keeping locks. Revise your application logic.

Comment: Could you post TEXT results of A) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%connect%'; and B) SELECT * FROM information_schema.global_status WHERE variable_name LIKE '%connect%' OR variable_name = 'uptime' ORDER BY variable_name 
;  ? Thank you.

Comment: character_set_connection utf8mb4
collation_connection utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
connect_timeout 10
disconnect_on_expired_password ON
init_connect 
max_connect_errors 100
max_connections 10606
max_user_connections 0
mysqlx_connect_timeout 30
mysqlx_max_connections 100
performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size 512

Comment: You are missing 'max_used_connections' and 'threads_connected' in your posted data.  It is unlikely your max_connections of 10606 requested in your configuration is reasonable.

Comment: Yes that parameter was set automatic by RDS its because my instance is very big

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the actual `UPDATE`.  You may change names if you like, but please don't change datatypes.  There may be something subtle happening.

Answer (score 1):

Finally was the auto commit as [mustaccio](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/23721/mustaccio) told me in a comment:

> Looks like your "sleep connections" are not committing their transactions and thus keeping locks. Revise your application logic.